# Reasons why sword duelling would exist on a Mars-like planet with unbreathable air

Tags: science-fiction, swords, guns

The civilisation on this planet has rockets and computers, so presumably they are smart enough to invent guns if they really want guns. Taking a sabre to a gunfight is clearly a terrible lifestyle choice, yet sword fighting is too sexy and awesome not to include in the story.

So, why do my heroes and villains carry swords and not handguns?

My first thought was "so as not to put a hole in the wall and lose all your precious air" but then I thought that might not be sufficient because they could just go outside and fight in pressure suits, or maybe fight in a house that was built with thick concrete walls/built underground to keep the solar radiation out.

Edited to add:
Yes, the civilisation came to the planet from Earth.
I would prefer reasons that explain why ordinary people, in general, do not have guns on this planet.

Comment: Hi Robyn. This is more than opinion-based, it's story-based. It appears you're not asking about a rule of your world (e.g., "given that the atmosphere is poisonous and accepting that the tradition of the people is to duel with swords, how could they conduct a sword fight outside the pressure domes?") but an aspect of your story or plot (e.g., "I want swordfighting in my story... how can I explain that?"). Before I vote to close as too story-based, can you convert this question to a world-rule question? What rule are you having trouble developing?

Comment: I think you answered your own question as far as guns go. So that only leaves the sword question, which I think you'll have to provide some details about. E.g.: what kind of people are these that can't breathe the atmosphere of their own planet!? Are they colonists from somewhere else? What are the cultures of that somewhere else like vis-a-vis swords for duelling? You've got a good underlying concept, but the question itself needs a lot of work!

Comment: That civilization likely got there from outside, not evolved on the planet (otherwise: how would you explain _aerobic_ life that is _not_ adjusted to the planet's atmosphere). My question is: why would they chose to switch from going unarmed in their everyday life to suddenly "Yeah, I'm still in an artificial habitat, like the ship that brought me here, but now I need to wear weapons"?

Comment: In this format it's opinion based and even too large. I suggest you start it with in what context do you picture your sword fighting happening. From there try to list the relevant information and word it in a suitable manner.
For example lets assume the people on the world came from a spaceship on which little firearms existed and the crew were given swords to use. Because of this they had little to begin with. Also no workshops or specialized experience or knowledge on how to make them. If I put an average person with a computer in a car factory they will not be able to make a gun...

Comment: No matter how advanced the civilization is. If they lack the knowledge and tools to do it. It's gonna be rough. Further the ruling class were officers, those who had guns, and they kinda liked this situation. Only they had guns and the rest had melee weapons so they posed little danger unless in numbers. This also suited the other classes as they had tools to defend themselves from the others that you expect to attack but not from higher ups but that fine. Another thing is if they found that guns just destroy the suits people wear and create big holes in the environment which can...

Comment: Destroy everything. So. Guns were never pursued to be made because the suit is as valuable as the human inside. And the habitats don't take kindly to gunshots. 
Maybe they are not trusted by the earth government to use guns and as such they are not exported any materials that can make guns. Perhaps the whole colony is a private company based and to dissuade rebellion the company ban guns and maybe uses some robots to enforce that particular law while leaving people to kinda club each other with swords.
Anyway we just need to know more. (3/3)

Comment: There are really 2 question here : (1) Why are there so many duels? and (2) Why are there no guns ?

Answer (score 4):

**They are not swords.**

[image: crowbar]

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrowbarCombatant

Your Outlanders might traverse many airlocks in the course of a day.  These are kept shut tight as a matter of survival.  They must be opened with a tool and then levered shut behind them with the same tool.

This tool is what every man, woman and child carries with them.  The tool is good for all kinds of things.  You do not fight with them as you would a sword but it is not far off.

Answer (score 3):

While modern firearms would 'work' since gunpowder contains fuel and oxidiser, given a suitably hostile environment, guns might be unreliable. Dust would cause delicate (and less delicate) moving parts to gum up or cause excessive wear, the ballistics of bullets would be different given lower gravity and so on. Magazines would be clogged up by dust, and liquid lubricants attract dust and turn every surface into an abrasive mess.

While I guess you could have a 'sealed' firing mechanism, you'd basically be restricted to derringer style weapons. You'd also need to learn to shoot with a helmet on.

If a planet is uninhabited by native life, you'd be unlikely to 'need' a gun outside other humans so guns might be uncommon anyway.

While 'primitive' - melee weapons would allow you to attack someone's suit, with a tear or rip potentially being dangerous, and significant damage lethal.

Considering low gravity and a relatively undeveloped planet outside the 'cities'- a 'strange' but useful weapon might be a vaulting pole - used to cross crevasses (used as a spear), or climbing picks

Answer (score 1):

## Because Guns are Too Powerful:

People are angry, violent and aggressive. They'll always find a reason to fight, and always feel it is a terrible thing. So what happens when fighting a war involves
nanites that can obliterate cities, plasma weapons that vaporize habitats, and killer droids that make humans obsolete?

Getting a better weapon in such a culture to get an advantage is a losing proposition, because there is ALWAYS a better weapon, and the tech to get better weapons is at hand for everyone. So fighting has reached a universal mutually assured destruction phase. Even "normal" guns have come to be viewed as gross, senseless killing tools for the crude and primitive. The history of mass shooting has poisoned gun use for all time. So where do you draw the line?

I read a Star Trek novel once where the crew visit a world where carrying a flintlock muzzle-loader pistol without any targeting ability was mandatory. The dueling culture was such that people could and would fight regularly over petty issues. But the advanced medical equipment, primitive weaponry and poor aim meant few people actually died in all that fighting.

People use swords because they are violent and potentially lethal, but not so much as to make them seem dishonorable. People carry swords because scanners will alarm at the presence of any weapon more sophisticated than a crossbow. People carry swords because they emphasize physical fitness and skill, and chicks dig guys good with a blade. Swords are high-tech enough that the gender disadvantage for women using melee weapons has closed (or perhaps physical differences between the genders has diminished). Swords mean you can swagger in a bar and if things go wrong, you'll most likely find yourself in an ambulance rather than a morgue. People carry swords because carrying a gun is punishable by death, but a sword is just a big tool, right?

But mostly, people carry swords because everyone knows that bringing a gun to a knife fight is a great way to get things completely out of hand.

Comment: "People are angry, violent and aggressive." In our world's reality, the jury [is still debating](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2019/jan/14/mutiny-on-the-sex-raft-70s-experiment-santiago-genoves) on this one

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your future materials technology has surpassed weapons technology, environmental suits have been designed to resist impacts from incredibly fast moving rocks flung by storms or even micro-meteorites, these suits could therefore be resistant to most firearms.
Theres a YouTube channel called Tod's Workshop with a video that demonstrated how a sandbag could stop a bullet whereas a crossbow bolt would fly straight through, perhaps the suits could work in a similar fashion provide resistance against a short hard impact by a light object but for longer heavier objects eventually the armour gives in, so a bullet would be useless but a long sharp sword like a rapier or a crossbow would be more likely to penetrate the armour.

Alternatively they could be heavily protected from the front and back by their suits but from the side they're vulnerable, so shooting at somebody is ineffective if they are charging towards you. The best option here may be to try to stab at the vulnerable areas with a sword or a spear.

Answer (score 0):

There’s nowhere to reliably make them.

Your colonists are supported by a lot of technology, and have been since they landed. 3D printers, highly automated refining/smelting/forging/machining, lots and lots of high tech computer controlled wizardry.

You’d think with all the production capacity they’d easily be able to make guns, right?

Wrong. The colonists have, over the years, lost a lot of knowledge. Reprogramming the manufactories is hard unless it’s something simple, something expected by the (admittedly very intuitive) user interface.

The machines never had instructions for making bullets, barrels, trigger mechanisms or even gunpowder uploaded. They’re unnecessary in a utopian colony, which this definitely is, right??.

In order to reinvent such weapons your colonists would have to not only come up with the concepts of firearms/offensive rocketry but also work around a whole load of computer systems and safeguards designed to make messing with the automated manufactories as hard as possible.

“Why are you asking me for low explosives in a metal case? ” Asks one manufacturing plant. “This action is not authorised. Only low yield mining charges can be produced at this station”.

“Why are you trying to disable the navigational safeguards on this rocket?” Asks another. “That’s clearly user error, so I’m going to add in a bunch of secondary systems to make sure you don’t accidentally crash into anyone and harm them, since clearly crashing a rocket into a building can’t be your intent”.

Even storing chemicals to roll your own proves difficult, with automated drones recognising potentially hazardous caches of material and shuffling them off to be safely stored, lest anyone accidentally get hurt!

By comparison programming a manufactory to produce a length of high quality steel that you can manually sharpen is very, very easy. So people do that. In the corridors and storage bays of the colony a good knife or short sword is just as effective as a gun, and you don’t have to spend decades trying to disable every security protocol and safeguard that might interfere with you making and operating the weapon,

Answer (score 0):

Mars is a barren place. If you are to traverse it from outpost to outpost, you might not see a human settlement for days. And resources are really precious, including ammunitions.

By the way, this is a theme not just on Mars, but on many futuristic works of fiction that take place on Earth (usually post-apocalyptic, but still). See [Nausica of the Valley of the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film)) for an example - people have advanced technology but still use swords frequently.

Back to Mars. If you fight frequently, you will soon run out of bullets. Once those run out you are left with more primitive means of [aggressive negotiations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzZxFEp16R8).

Now someone might say that swords wear out with time too. The good news is that a sword will be much less vulnerable to rust in an atmosphere that's got practically no free oxygen. And iron on Mars is way more abundant than iron on Earth. And you need much less technology to craft and repair swords than what you need to fix guns and craft ammo.

Last but not least:

> sword fighting is too sexy and awesome not to include in the story.

You know what else is sexy? Archery. Mars has ~37% the gravity of Earth, and its atmosphere is less than 1% as thick as ours. Arrows shot on Mars would have some unbelievable range.

"Wait, arrows won't be accurate because the fletching will have practically no drag in that atmosphere, thus making the arrows terribly inaccurate!" Not actually. Yes, in the hands of the novice or unprepared, a bow on Mars might be so erratic as to be useless. But consider that professionals tune their bows with bare shafts. If the bow is perfectly tuned and a pro is using it, a fletchess arrow will be practically as accurate as a fletched one. What this all means is that to even fire a bow in the atmosphere of Mars would require mastery, but the archer might reasonably be able to shoot at target a thousand yards away. A typical range for a longbow on Earth is about 350 yeards - it would be much more than that in martian conditions.

You could also make the shafts out of steel or carbon fiber rather than wood.

Answer (score 0):

**Airlock Security.**

[image]

Dueling with Guns inside the Space Dome might sound like a really good idea, right? Wrong! It is a really bad idea. You  will make a hole in the Space Dome and let in all the Space Air and choke all the colonists to death. So no one has guns and they are very illegal.

Of course you could smuggle a gun and invite your enemy outside the Space Dome for a shooting match. However you will get caught, since airlocks entry and exit are heavily surveilled. This is easy to do since the Space dome has only 3 possible entry/exit points.

Instead people duel with sharp weapons indoors.  It is much harder to outlaw sharp things since they are needed for all sorts of non-duelling tasks.

I leave it to you why people have duels at all. In the modern world duels using either swords or guns are illegal and uncommon.